# How to change a single linked list into doubly linked list

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm having trouble changing this single linked list into a doubly linked list so that I can print a string of characters (the char s[] variable) backwards. I don't want to reverse the linked list, just print it in reverse, while using a doubly linked list. So how do I implement a doubly linked list with the following code?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class node
{
  public:
  char data;
  node *next;
  node *prev;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char s[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    node *head; //start of list
    node *temp;
    node *current;

    head = new node;          // create the head of the linked list
    head->data = s[0];
    head->next = NULL;
    temp = head;   // get ready for the loop - save the head in temp - you are going to change temp in the loop

    for(size_t i=1; i < strlen(s); i++)      // create the rest of the linked list
    {
        current = new node;    // make a new node
        current->data = s[i];  // set it's data member
        current->next = NULL;
        temp->next = current;  // point to the new node
        temp = current;        // make temp point to current node (for next time through)
    }

    node *ptr = head;    // set a ptr to head, then increment the pointer

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        cout << ptr->data; // print out the linked list
        ptr = ptr->next;   // increment the linked list
    }

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the question you want to ask ?

Comment: @PankajBansal How do I implement a doubly linked list here and print the char s[] backwards

Comment: You're not initializing any of the `prev` pointers on newly created nodes so far. That would be a good place to start ...

Comment: @dragosht I knew I would need that, I'm not sure where to use it though.

Comment: Well ... Looks like everywhere you create a new node you already initialize the `next` pointer. Just go ahead and add the `prev` pointer initialization in there.

Comment: `temp` is initialised on the heap outside the loop then immediately overwritten by `head`. That's a memory leak. Also, initialise your prev pointers.

Comment: @AndyBrown Yeah I was working on writing something else and forgot to take that out when I posted this; edited it out. What line am I going to initialize the prev pointers?

Comment: You'd do it inside the loop. Use the node constructor to default prev, next to null. Create a 'last' pointer initialised to null. Set current->prev to 'last' and if last!=null then set last->next to current. Then set last to current for the next trip around the loop. This is homework so the implementation is yours to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
   char data;
   node *next;
   node *prev;
   node(char Data, node* Prev, node* Next);
};

node::node(char Data, node* Prev, node* Next)
    : data(Data), prev(Prev), next(Next)
{
    if (prev)prev->next = this;
    if (next)next->prev = this;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char s[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    node *temp;
    node *current;

    node *head; // ptr to head of list
    node *tail; // ptr to tail of list

    // call constructor and initialize first node 
    head = tail = new node(s[0], NULL, NULL);

    for (size_t i = 1; i < strlen(s); i++) // create the rest of the linked list
    {
        tail = new node(s[i], tail, NULL);
    }

    node *ptr = head; // set a ptr to head, then you are going to "increment" the pointer

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        cout << ptr->data; // print out the linked list
        ptr = ptr->next;   // increment the linked list
    }

    node *ptr1 = tail; // set a ptr to tail, then "decrement" the pointer form z to a
    cout << endl;

    while (ptr1 != NULL)
    {
        cout << ptr1->data; // print out the linked list
        ptr1 = ptr1->prev; // decrement the linked list
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```